# Insert dynamic content into static HTML

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc

My requirement is to insert some dynamic content into a static HTML file from the Database. I am able to do this on the client side using javascript.

The actual requirement is to take the values from the Database and insert the values into fields in the static HTML.

For example, this is how I think the static HTML would look like

```html
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         <p>The first name is (Insert first name from DB)</p>
         <p>The second name is (Insert last name from the DB)</p>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

The static HTML is already saved locally or it might be present on the server.

I am planning to build a console application in .NET which does this. How would I be able to achieve this?

I have searched the website and didn't see something similar.

Comment: Console application does not have views. You  need to create .net core application.

Comment: Console application is not going to return a view. The application will insert data into static HTML and convert the HTML into PDF. I have not asked the PDF part in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

now i got you.

assuming a template like this:

```
<html>
    <head> </head>
    <body>
        hi ##YourName##
    </body>
</html>
```

your program could look like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // load template
        var template = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\template.html");

        var content = template.Replace("##YourName##", "value From Db");

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\static_html_file_1.html", content);
    }
}
```

with a result of:

```
<html>
    <head> </head>
    <body>
        hi value From Db
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was talking about. Let me try it out.

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel. Unless you're dealing with an extremely simple case (like...EXACTLY what this example shows) then you should use some existing and well tested template engine. There are .NET packages for (just to mention few) Mustache, Handlebars, Liquid...

Comment: It may not as simple as the example I mentioned. Its possible there might be tables involved as well.The tables also should get rendered dynamically. I will also look into the existing templates in .NET

Comment: It was about giving an idea.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Your input definitely helped me in getting started.